# What does selecting CALayer in View Effects Inspector inside Interface Builder do?

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode4, interface-builder, core-animation

Inside IB, in View Effects Inspector, there is an option to set Core Animation Layer. If I set it what does it do?

[image: View Effects Inspector]

Is it equivalent to `setWantsLayer:YES`?

If so then as per [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsview_Class/Reference/NSView.html) `setWantsLayer` can be called before or after `setLayer:`.

`The order that setWantsLayer: and setLayer: are called is important, it makes the distinction between a layer-backed view and a layer-hosting view.`

If I set CALayer from IB, which order would it be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The checkbox makes your view *layer-backed* (like calling `setWantsLayer:` without `setLayer:`).