# NSButton being clipped with CAAnimation

Tags: macos, calayer, nsbutton, caanimation

So I'm doing a simple animation on an `NSButton` that I found [here](http://www.objc.io/issue-12/animations-explained.html)

```
button.wantsLayer = YES;
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
animation.keyPath = @"position.x";
animation.values = @[ @0, @10, @-10, @10, @0 ];
animation.keyTimes = @[ @0, @(1 / 6.0), @(3 / 6.0), @(5 / 6.0), @1 ];
animation.duration = 0.5;
animation.additive = YES;
[button.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"shake"];
```

Except, when it does wiggle side to side, it gets clipped (this is kinda hard to screenshot so here goes)

[image]

You can see, on the right side of the "2" button (the one that is being animated), the shadow/bevel is being clipped/cut off.

I thought this might be a clipsToBounds thing, but neither the button or the layer has such a property (maybe its an iOS only thing, where my background is)?

Any ideas/solutions would be appreciated :)

Comment: It definitely looks clipped — is it just the one button that is clipped? If so try duplicating one of the other buttons and replace the faulty one with the copy.

Comment: All the buttons are being clipped :/

Comment: Maybe if you post your project (or a basic form of it) someone can take a better look.

Comment: Yea, Sam, got a demo project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue in my project by giving the button super view its own `CALayer` by selecting the view in IB then going to the "View Effects Inspector" and checking the tick box under "Core Animation Layer". I'm sure you could do this programmatically, but <s>I'm unsure if that layer is "backed" or "hosted"</s>. **Edit:** according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277573/what-does-selecting-calayer-in-view-effects-inspector-inside-interface-builder-d) it is layer backed FYI.

There may be some other key differences between our setups so if this doenst workout you let me know and I'll look into it.

It's probably irrelevant, but I'm using `CABasicAnimation` instead of `CAKeyFrameAnimation`

Comment: Perfect. The trick was to change that setting on the view that held the buttons. Thanks!

Comment: @SamJarman yes, thats what was meant by `superview`, sorry if that wasnt clear. Glad it worked for you; there are a ton of odd gottchas like this with CoreAnimation unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0):

The animation is restricted to the bounds of the CALayer, which is defined by the view.  So the clipping happens when the image moves beyond the bounds of the Button's view.  There is probably a smarter way, but embedding the NSButton within a slightly larger NSView and shaking that view seems to work.